# Magento 2 - Wrong version number in footer

Tags: magento2, upgrade, version

Today I updated Magento 2.0.2 to 2.0.3 with Web Setup Wizard successfully.

But in admin footer is still the old version number of 2.0.2. How can it be?

I cleared the cache and the `pub/static` folder. No difference.

Comment: An issue can be found on the official github: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3939

Comment: Yes we are working on it. Please see the github link posted by Raphael

Answer (score 4):

This was a [Bug in 2.0.3](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3939#issuecomment-203932412) and is fixed in 2.0.4